# display dataframe inside cell of dash ag-grid

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am developing a `dash` app and exploring `dash ag-grid` component. I am trying to display a `pandas dataframe` inside cell grid, using `dash bootstrap component.table`.

I am using references from [here](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-ag-grid/cell-renderer-components#example-3:-cell-renderer-with-dbc.button)

```
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "First Name": ["Arthur", "Ford", "Zaphod", "Trillian"],
        "Last Name": ["Dent", "Prefect", "Beeblebrox", "Astra"],
    }
)

df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame({"contents": [data, data, data]})

grid: dag.AgGrid = dag.AgGrid(
   id="data_grid",
   columnDefs=[
        {
           "field": "contents",
           "headerName": "Data",
           "cellRenderer": "TableCellRenderer",
        },
    ],
    columnSize="responsiveSizeToFit",
    style={"height": 500, "width": "100%"},
    rowData=df.to_dict("records"),
) 

# dashAgGridComponentFunctions.js

dagcomponentfuncs.TableCellRenderer = function (props) {
    return React.createElement(window.dash_bootstrap_components.Table.from_dataframe, {
        df: props.value,
        striped: false,
        bordered: false,
        hover: false,
        index: false,
        style: {height: '100%', width: '100%'},      
    });
};
```

I am getting error as below:

```
Error: Minified React error #130; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

# on clicking above link
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: [missing argument].[missing argument]
```

What I am missing?